# Is it possible to export a CSV file with Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, dql

Since there is no OUTFILE capabilities with Doctrine as far as I can tell, how would one export a query as a CSV file?

In MySQL, for example, the query would be:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM table;
```

How could the same be done with Doctrine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting to csv file with Doctrine and Symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009271/exporting-to-csv-file-with-doctrine-and-symfony)

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, I would to something like:

```
FETCH records in Doctrine_Core::FETCH_NUM mode
foreach records as record:
    save record in csv using fputcsv
```

References: [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)