# Exporting to csv file with Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm working on exporting from a database table using Doctrine and symfony. I've made a call to my database with

```
$variableTable = Doctrine::getTable('Table Name')->findAll();
```

then I set another variable to get data from it like so:

```
$variable = $variableTable->getData();
```

I just want to be able to loop through that so I can pull the data I need to put into a csv file but I'm stuck on that part. For some reason, when I debug, it shows that the second variable that is getting set to the value of the getData is null/0.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 11):

I think maybe you are trying to call `getData` on the collection instead of calling `getData` on the record... But that doesnt make much sense because you are still going to have to call `getData` on each record, so you might as well just loop over the collection. Additionally its possible there were no results from your `findAll` for some crazy reason so you should take that into account i think. Anyhow code similar to the following has worked for me in the past so without the details of your code its the best i can offer:

```
$records = Doctrine::getTable('RecordName')->findAll();

if($records->count()) {
   $csvPath = '/path/to/csv/file.csv';

   $csvh = fopen($csvPath, 'w');
   $d = ','; // this is the default but i like to be explicit
   $e = '"'; // this is the default but i like to be explicit

   foreach($records as $record) {
       $data = $record->toArray(false); // false for the shallow conversion
       fputcsv($csvh, $data, $d, $e);
   }

   fclose($csvh);

  // do something with the file
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, please modify fuputcsv to fputcsv.

Comment: How well does it work with large datasets ? Isn't it going to fill up the memory ?

Comment: With large datasets I tend to batch them.

Answer (score 1):

There are existing solutions for data import\export.

Consider using one of this:

- https://github.com/orocrm/platform/tree/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ImportExportBundle
- https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter